# How do defib revives affect the kill/death count in a Battlefield 3 match?

Tags: battlefield-3

When an Assault-kit player revives a teammate with the defibrillator, does that subtract the last kill credited for the enemy team in the match? Does that also subtract the last kill credited for the enemy player himself who killed that teammate that was just revived?

What happens when the revive goes bad, and the same teammate is killed again? Does that count as one or two kills for the enemy team? And does that count as two kills for the enemy player who killed that teammate, then killed him again after the revive, or just one kill?

This could be considered a question related to the mechanics of revives or defibrillator use in Battlefield 3, and it should help some Assault-kit players out there make smarter choices about how and when they revive.

Thanks for anyone taking the time to provide accurate information and answers.

Comment: if you revive an ally that ally then does not receive a "death" but the enemy who shot him does still receive a "kill". If your ally gets shot again you cant revive him since you can only revive an ally once a life. Killing your ally a second time does give a second kill for the enemy.

Comment: That's not true, you can revive someone more than once. The only time you can not revive someone (appart from glitches) is when he was just revived and hasn't accepted the revive yet. If he is up on his feet again and dies, he can be revived again.

Comment: Seconded; I have revived the same person again more times than I can count. Can't say that I remember reviving the same person a third time within the same 5 seconds or so, but reviving the same person twice? Definitely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tickets in BF3 in all modes except CTF (score is based on flag caps) are not like in Bad Company 2.

In BF3, **spawning cost your team a ticket** (except for the first spawn I think). So, as long as you don't use the spawn screen, the enemy team is not credited a ticket/your team is not subtracted one (depending on the mode). If the revives goes bad, since it's only the spawn that affect the ticket, the enemy team does not get double tickets/your team does not get subtracted double tickets.

However, **for personal stats, as soon as you kill someone the player is credited the kill.** So if you kill some one, the guy gets revived and you kill him again (before he gets up or after, it doesn't matter), you'll get credited two kills. That is the reason maps like metro 24/7 64 players are good for levelling up fast. There are so many revives that the game last way longer and so many people that getting kills is easy. Also, **when you die, your death is not attributed your body is un-revivable**..

The only disadvantage of doing bad revives in BF3 is that your teammate will be mad at you since he'll have to wait longer until being able to re-spawn. For this reason, if you want your revive to actually help your team, clear the area before. That will also help you not getting shot in the face with your defibs out which will end up giving/subtracting 2 tickets instead of one.

EDIT: Changed how the death is counted and CQ death count.

Comment: You got a couple of things wrong here: 1) Your remark about Conquest Domination is not true, killing players also takes away tickets. (on of many sources: http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Conquest) 2) You can be revived when you are in the spawning screen, happens a lot to me. You can't be revived if you've already spawned again (of course)

Comment: Thank you, Hugo, for a very satisfactory answer; that clarifies the issue for me. And thank you for the corrections, Sentry.

Answer (score 1):

Best to describe with an example:

SCORE: Player A - 0-0 / Player B - 0-0

> Player A kills player B
>   SCORE: Player A - 1-0 / Player B - 0-0
>   
>   Player B NOT revived
>   SCORE: Player A - 1-0 / Player B - 0-1
>   
>   Player B gets revived and immidiately after that killed again by Player A
>   SCORE: Player A - 2-0 / Player B - 0-1